# If $f$ be a uniformly continuous function on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is bounded there.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

We define a continuous extension of $f(x)$ to the set $[a,b]$, by $g(x)=f(x), x\in (a,b)$ and $g(a)= \lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x)$ and $g(b)=\lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x)$. $g(x)$ being continuous on a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$, it is bounded. So, $f$ being a restriction of $g$, it must also be bounded.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think you need to argue that the limits exist. **If** the limits exist, then this method works.

Comment: @Clayton they must. Because $f$ is uniformly continuous. (Proof is manageable). And after showing that the limits exist, then I move on to my procedure. Will that be alright?

Comment: Correct! ${}{}{}$

Comment: You can show that the limits exist but you can also show that $f$ is bounded without first showing that the limits exist.